# Function merges and returns n bytes from array of bytes

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a type independent vector in C. Partly to avoid dealing with `void*`:s and partly because I read somewere to use more representative types I decided to represent my data as an array of bytes or `uint8_t`:s. Now let's say I would like to store integers in said array, I was thinking that then you could just take up 4 places in the array for the value. But I can't find a good way of achiving something like that.

One thought I had was to simply mask every byte of the integer and store it in a looping fashion like:

| BYTES | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INTEGER | 0xCA | 0x36 | 0x52 | 0x11 |
| ARRAY | index 0 | index 1 | index 2 | index 3 |

*NOTE: I just used random values to exemplify*

And to retrive the integer I would shift and or together the bytes.

The ideal solution would be if I could point to a location in the array and then retrive a block of n bytes but I have not found any way of doing that?

**Is there a way to retrive a block of n bytes, or is the better solution just to use void pointers?**

To represent my vector I use a struct like:

```
typedef struct vector{
    size_t size;
    size_t used;
    size_t data_size;

    uint8_t* data;
}vec;
```

And to store data I would: (major pseudocode maybe not even right)

```
const int mask = 0x000000ff

for(int i = 0; i < vec -> data_size;i++){
    *(vec -> data + vec -> used * vec->data_size + i) = integer >> 8*(vec->data_size - i) & mask
}
```

Comment: To store an object in an array, use `memcpy(destination, &object, sizeof object)`. `destination` would be a pointer into the array, such as `vec->data + offset`. To retrieve the object, reverse the first two arguments.

Comment: You don't need an array of masks; right shift the value by 0, 8, 16 or 24, and unconditionally mask with `0xFF`.

Comment: Why at all do you want to loose that bit of type safety in C? This looks to me like a dubious software design. Please [edit] your question and add a bit of background. -- Other than that, Eric's comment would make a good answer. Simply use `memcpy()`, but be aware of endianness and different sizes of the same types, if you share the byte array among different systems.